# What interesting question lists can you generate from the data dump

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I know, this is a really REALLY broad.

What kind of interesting question lists can you generate from the data dump (that you can not get by using the SO UI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one I prepared earlier.

List of all the unanswered questions by people with more than 5000 rep. (note I can not exclude closed questions as the info is missing from the dump) Also some of the list is out of date.

```
select '[' + Title + '](' + 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/' + cast(Id as varchar(max)) + ' "link")  <br/>' from Questions 
where Id in 
(
select q.id from Questions q
left join Answers a on q.Id = a.ParentId 
group by q.id
having isnull(sum(case when a.score < 0 then 0 else a.score end),0) = 0 
) 
and OwnerUserId in (select Id from Users where reputation > 5000)
and AcceptedAnswerId is null
and IsWiki = 0
order by CreationDate desc
```

1. [In Eclipse 3.5 (and with the Aptana plugins), how do I get a view that I can use to show my project, including "dot" files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066450)
2. [how to use the Automation object model of Microsoft Office packages (Word, Excel, etc.) in "plain" COM/ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064372)
3. [Community like features in bug tracking software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061195)
4. [can i view aspnet.db in sql server 2008 management studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061194)
5. [Is there a way to transfer external files using Aptana's FTP browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061009)
6. [What is causing the jumps here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061000) [deleted]
7. [Sister-Sites Greasemonkey Concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060720) [deleted]
8. [Click event fires in IE/Firefox, but Chrome is dropping the event assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060345)
9. [How is Scala "filling in" missing arguments to a case class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058642)
10. [What does the remote-actor framework do if trying to write to a client which is no longer there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058473)
11. [How can I identify a remote actor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058450)
12. [PostgreSQL ODBC driver not showing up in Control Panel (Data Sources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057575)
13. [How do i readlink -f on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671)
14. [How can I hide the space to the left of menu items in XAML menus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054930)
15. [How can I prevent input controls from stealing the space character from the TextCompositionManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053533)
16. [IE MIME/content filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052141)
17. [How can I control IE6+jQuery+jQuery-ui memory leaks ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051090)
18. [Simplest way of updating SQL Server 2005 from a REST web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050090)
19. [Forcing HttpOnly cookies with JRun/ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048436)
20. [IUI way to display invalid password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045622)
21. [What is the standard parallel GC called in JVM crash dumps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045119)
22. [Is there a file-based equivalent to .htaccess in IIS6? (not config/plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044820)
23. [Are static functions isolated in JSP/Grails applications under tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043950)
24. [Quickly Convert (.rtf|.doc) Files to Markdown Syntax with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043768)
25. [Visual Studio 2005 .vcproj files won't stay encoded as UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042915)
26. [IsValidLocale returns FALSE - how to overcome this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042811)
27. [What is the best way to post embedded audio (.wma) on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041423) [deleted]
28. [Access the project file structure within the Visual Studio Properties property grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040691)
29. [Profile Providers without web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039411) [deleted]
30. [Creating a "Heartbeat" or Windows-Service-Like functionality in Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038646)
31. [Is it meaningful to override the '==' method in ActiveRecord subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038539)
32. [FolderBrowserDialog takes eons to list the subfolders of a folder located in an USB drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037957)
33. [difficulties getting a simple envers example to work: problem #34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033375)
34. [CHECKSUM() collisions in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029057)
35. [When user clicks on icon area of MenuItem, DelegateCommand does not fire.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027993) [deleted]
36. [CSS text alignment alternative for buttons on a BlackBerry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027755) [deleted]
37. [Finding the right pattern for loading objects with different graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027728)
38. [JavaBeans and DSLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027516)
39. [Circular resource references causing issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024264)
40. [How to use System.Web.Abstractions in a Web Forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023787)
41. [How to properly implement a custom session persister in PHP + MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022416)
42. [Adsense in a AJAX heavy webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020855)
43. [model view controler in grails with out database backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019728)
44. [Tool for finding ways to get an object instance inside the debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019567)
45. [Visual Studio Unit Testing Accessor, how to re-generate them without closing VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019561)
46. [Creating a network adapter - how hard is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017005)
47. [Can WPF print PDF and Office files directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016873)
48. [Are other companies/products/websites providing access via Google Data APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016539)
49. [Grails web flow testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015588) [deleted]
50. [Does the dot Directed Graph allow for subgraphs with a different rankdir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014092)

The list goes on but I have no clean way of displaying it here.

Comment: Can anyone think of a way I can post links plus descriptions and not take out the UI?

Comment: Append two spaces on the end of each question link in your query.  then you can post the results here easily and it will include the line breaks.

Comment: guys, seriously, **PLEASE** read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help -- it is FULL of REALLY GOOD INFO.

Comment: @Jeff, I did - I'm still a bit lost on how to get the scroll box around a long list of links.

Answer (score 0):

This might result in interesting filters to display questions on the frontpage:
only show me posts from users with rep +5k related to C

Though that would require some change of the SO UI... and is not really answering your question either...