# How do I effectively post a long list of links?

Tags: feature-request, questions, editor

In [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4993/what-interesting-question-lists-can-you-generate-from-the-data-dump/4994#4994) I really wanted to post 500 hyperlinks.

```
Now I know, this is an edge case, 
but.... 

If I have a code block or a pre block 
I get a nice scrolly bar on the right hand side

when 
stuff 
gets 
too 
long 




























finish demo.
```

Is there any way I can get the same scrolly box for a list of clickable links?

Comment: Isn't there a web page for hosting such links? LinkedIn? I think there is also a link cap per entry?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge linkedin is a social networking website. I have thought of just hosting the list.

Comment: Post it on your blog. I don't know if the applet html tag still works here, but you could just create an applet with a scrollbox around a list of links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this issue resolved, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248764/formatting-link-lists-using-tsql) on stackoverflow.

[exec spShog9](http://gist.github.com/165544)

Get pretty results:

#### User           Reputation 
Questions Answers

```
Edward Tanguay 8317 465 24 
me             5767 311 29 
Joan Venge     4844 226 14 
Blankman       4546 310 1  
acidzombie24   4359 371 32 
Thanks         4350 416 21 
Masi           4193 555 74 
LazyBoy        3230 94  12 
KingNestor     3187 92  11 
Nick           2084 79  6  
George2        1973 263 1  
Xaisoft        1944 174 12 
John           1929 160 24 
danmine        1901 53  3  
zsharp         1771 145 16 
carrier        1742 56  8  
JC Grubbs      1550 50  5  
vg1890         1534 56  2  
Coocoo4Cocoa   1514 143 0  
Keand64        1513 83  5  
Masi           4193 555 74 
LazyBoy        3230 94  12 
KingNestor     3187 92  11 
Nick           2084 79  6  
George2        1973 263 1  
Xaisoft        1944 174 12 
John           1929 160 24 
danmine        1901 53  3  
zsharp         1771 145 16 
carrier        1742 56  8  
JC Grubbs      1550 50  5  
vg1890         1534 56  2  
Coocoo4Cocoa   1514 143 0  
Keand64        1513 83  5
```

Abridged:

```
<h3>User&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reputation 
Questions Answers </h3>
<pre>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/40882">Coocoo4Cocoa</a>   1514 143 0  
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/98188">Keand64</a>        1513 83  5
</pre>
```

Comment: This has the added benefit that the numbers at the end, line up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

IMO 500 links is getting into spam-esque proportions...

Comment: The thing is, that nothing is stopping you posting 500 links today, the only problem is that your post will end up being 500 lines long which is not desirable.... will probably just host this offsite. The hacker in me wants to find out if this is possible.

Comment: Fun experiment; post 500 links on a single reply and see how long it stays before getting spam-voted into oblivion ;-p

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
1. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
2. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
3. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
4. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
5. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
6. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
7. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
8. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
9. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
10. Link 1      2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
11. Link 1      2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
12. Link 1      2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
13. Link 1      2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
```

Poor man's table with short descriptions. Still no scrollbars, but at least more concise.

Comment: That wouldn't be the most helpful if you have longer titles.

Comment: Don't worry, will remove my post if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put links inside a set of `<pre>` tags, which will start scrolling when the size gets too big. You could then make your own list that way.

**Edit**: Apparently you can't do that. I also attempted using the BlockQuote, which will work for links, but will not actually start scrolling.

Someone give us a happy compromise here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want scrollbars, multi post the parts and you'll get the site scrollbar for free.

```
1. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
2. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
3. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
4. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
5. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
6. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
7. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
8. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
9. Link 1       2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
10. Link 1      2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
11. Link 1      2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
12. Link 1      2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
13. Link 1      2. Link 3       3. Link 3     3. Link 4       3. Link 5
```

Comment: Don't worry, will remove my post if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think posting the links in SO is a good solution.  There are very few, if any, situations where a long list of links is appropriate.  In the question you link to, it could have been easily resolved by providing a link to some other page containing those links.  Blogs cost nothing; sign up for one and dump it all there.